# How to get an object with a form and then send it to the next view using urls?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to send an object obtained with a **ModelChoiceField** into a view via urls and views parameters by I don't think that's the right method. I don't know if I have to use **POST** or **GET** method.

When I use the **GET** method, the object is displayed in the url but the view stay the same.
With the **POST** method, django send errors messages about parameters.

EDIT : I don't remeber the exact messages, I can't recover them for now but as I remember they said something like `Reverse for argument not found`

My form

```py
class IndividuForm(forms.Form):
    individu = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Individu.objects.all()
```

Here's the view with the form

```py
def index(request):
    individu_form = IndividuForm(request.GET or None)
    if individu_form.is_valid():
        individu_id = individu_form.cleaned_data['individu'].id
        HttpResponseRedirect('%i/raison/' % individu_id)
    return render(request, 'derog_bv/index.html', {'individu_form':individu_form})
```

The template where the form is displayed

```html
<form action="{% url 'index' <!-- Errors when I put parameters here --> %} method="<!-- GET or POST -->">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
<input type="submit">Suivant</input>
</form>
```

The view where I want to get my object

```py
def raison(request, """ error with this parameter : individu_id"""):
    individu = get_object_or_404(Individu, pk=individu_id)
```

URLs

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:individu_id>/raison/', views.raison, name='raison'),
]
```

Comment: Please post your urls and the exact error message(s) you get.

Comment: Note that you want to use GET here (it's a kind of a search form, you're not submitting data for database changes). Also, you want to learn to use named urls and `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` (the python version of the `{% url %}` templatetag) instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Oh and yes: you DONT want to pass parameters to the `url` tag in your index template. Actually you don't need to set the "action" attribute of the form (it defaults to the current url).

Comment: Thanks for help, I edited what you said it was missing. I can't continue today, I will be back tommorrow to try your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so:

1/ you definitly want to use the GET method for your form (you're not submitting data for processing / server state change)

2/ I don't know why you'd want to pass parameters (nor which parameters FWIW) to the `{% url %}` tag in your index template - you're submitting the form to the index view, which doesn't expect any additional param. Actually you could just remove the `action` attribute of the HTML form tag since the default (submitting to the current url) is what you want.

3/ your `views.raison` prototype must match the url definition, so it has to be:

```
def raison(request, individu_id):
    # code here
```

4/ in your index view:

```
HttpResponseRedirect('%i/raison/' % individu_id)
```

you want to build the url using `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` instead :

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def index(request):
   # code here
   if ...:
       next = reverse("raison", kwargs={"individu_id": individu_id}) 
       return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

or - even easier - just use [the `redirect` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def index(request):
   # code here
   if ...:
       return redirect("raison", individu_id=individu_id)
```

There might be other issues with your code but from the infos you posted, those hints should at least put you back on tracks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried what you said but I got an error that I don't understand : ```Reverse for 'raison' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['derog_bv\\/(?P<individu_id>[0-9]+)\\/raison\\/$']```

Comment: @Zapoux Are we supposed to guess which __exact__ code causes this error ?

Comment: ```return redirect("raison", individu_id=individu_id)```

Comment: This code cannot produce this error. The error message you get comes from calling `redirect` _without_ the `individu_id` param.